# Python: if No XML tag , print 'Blank' along with Output

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

```
data="<database>
<zone1>
<name>
<firstname>John</firstname> 
<lastname>cena</lastname> 
<job>Administrator</job> 
<location>sunnyvale</location> 
<age>19</age> 
</name>
</zone1>

<zone2>
<name>
<firstname>mark</firstname> 
<job>Agent</job> 
<location>Bangalore</location> 
<age>22</age> 
</name>
</zone2>

<zone3>
<name>
<firstname>patrick</firstname> 
<lastname>phillips</lastname>
<job>Developer</job> 
<location>Philadelphia</location> 
<age>28</age> 
</name>
</zone3>

<zone4>
<name>
<firstname>patrick</firstname> 
<job>Developer</job> 
<location>Philadelphia</location> 
<age>28</age> 
</name>
</zone4>
</database>"    

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,lxml')

last_name=[v.get_text() if soup.find_all('lastname') else 'blank' for v in soup.find_all('lastname')]
print (last_name)
```

This is output for the above code.

> ['cena','phillips']

What is the wrong with the above code? Anyone tell me what needs to be changed for the above code? I want the below Output. (i.e. if XML tag doesn't exist 'blank' should be added)

> ['cena','blank','phillips','blank']

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')

last_name=[v.find('lastname').get_text() if v.find('lastname') else 'blank' for v in soup.find_all('name')]
print (last_name)
```

- Find all `name` tag  --> `soup.find_all('name')`
- Check if `name` has `lastname` tag --> `if v.find('lastname')`